# How to allow a user to see only his project and hide rest of the project in odoo portal

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to give the access to the portal user to view the project status. But the condition is , I need to hide the rest of projects from the user. Can anyone suggest me the record rule for change the visibility in the portal..??

Can you suggest a record rule for that? It will be thankful.. I tried with many record rule, but doesn't worked...

Comment: just create the record rules and for the user

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you suggest a record rule for that? It will be thankful.. I tried with many record rule, but doesn't worked...

Comment: please edit your question and add it within that so that every can easily understand what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of security rule:

`owner_uid` will be your custom field.

```xml
<data noupdate="1">
    <record id="record_rule_id" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Rule Name</field>
        <field ref="base.model_model_name" name="model_id"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('owner_uid','=',user.id)]</field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_of_user'))]"/>
    </record>
</data>
```